# unpivot with different destination columns in SSIS Dataflow

Tags: ssis, sql-server-data-tools, unpivot

I've got a pivot-table like this;

```
DAccount, DObject, DDep, DSum, CAccount, CObject, CDep, CSum
4851,301,43,201407.42,4813,121,55,-201407.42
```

and I like to unpivot it so it will look like this;

```
Account, Object, Dep, Sum
4851,301,43,201406.42
4813,121,55,-201406.42
```

I've tried searching for tips on unpivot, but all examples uses same destination column. I think its the Pivot Key Value I have problem understanding.
I've set destination columns to Account, Object, Dep and Sum (Account on both DAccount and CAccount etc). In the Pivot Key value its the default, ie same as input column.
When I press ok on this its says Key values need to match exactly, and I tried changeing them but then it says they need to be unique.

All help is appreciated!

Comment: Is there a Line item or some surrogate key that would uniquely identify this row in the source? Otherwise, you're looking at an asynchronous Script Component, acting as a transformation (1 row in = 2 rows out === asynchronous)

Comment: no, no key at the moment. I might be able to add a DKey and CKey if that helps.